# How to get the Count of visitors webpag using Razor ASP.Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

i am using ASP.Core Razor pages and i want to get the number or count of visitors like 22 visitor has been visiting this webpage .

How is the idea of that ! 
i will be so glad for a help .

thanks

Comment: add a counting field that increases whenever the page is fetched and save it to the db with ip, date, time, page title, etc., but it is easier and more efficient to use online service like google analytics or yandex metrica

Comment: @LazZiya. thanks i will try it

Comment: It's better to track this in a separate table. Just record the URL, datetime, and any discriminator(s) you want to use such as IP address, username, etc. (to prevent multiple counts of the same user). Then, when you need a count, you can aggregate it from this table. This turns the recording of a view into an insert, rather than an update (when using a column-based view count). Updates require consideration of concurrency, which is generally going to require locking or otherwise gating reads and writes, which gets complicated quickly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for your answer ..could you show me some code or send me a link support what did u write even to get it better .